# Using reflection methods that take array parameters efficiently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

Currently I'm using some static arrays to avoid creating garbage for reflection methods that take arrays:

```
public static readonly object[]
    OneObject = new object[1],
    TwoObjects = new object[2];
```

Then I use them like:

```
public void Write(BinaryWriter writer, object value)
{
    Reflection.TwoObjects[0] = writer;
    Reflection.TwoObjects[1] = value;
    WriteMethod.Invoke(null, Reflection.TwoObjects);
}
```

Most of the time this will be fine, but it opens the door to multithreading bugs.

Is there a better way of doing this without allocating tiny arrays all over the place?

Comment: Do you know the signature of the method you're using reflection to invoke? i.e the parameter types?

Comment: I use the arrays all over the place to invoke lots of different methods. In each specific case I do know the parameter types.

Comment: Side note: there are likely much better ways to do whatever you trying to do rather than using reflection... (and it is not yet clear that you've found that actual array creation is main performance problem in your code)

Comment: Better way is dont use public variable, make it public properties and add lock there.

Comment: @Stanley I don't think that would work. If Reflection.TwoObjects is a property, it can only lock while it is being set. I'd need to lock the array for the whole duration of my Write method (and every other method that uses the array).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm quite certain that these arrays are not causing any sort of performance problem. I'm just trying to find the best way to do something because I'm not in a hurry to get it done.

Comment: You probably should have asked differently like "I'm trying to achieve ZZZZZZ, right now I'm using reflections with following code but..."

Comment: But that's what I did. _I'm doing X to avoid creating garbage_ ... _Is there a better way of doing this_. You're the one who brought up performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the signature of the underlying method, you can create a strongly typed delegate and invoke it instead. For example (assuming `method` is a `MethodInfo` instance that represents a static method that returns `void` and takes a `BinaryWriter` and an `object` as parameters):

```
var myMethod = (Action<BinaryWriter, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<BinaryWriter, object>), method);
myMethod(writer, obj);
```

An added benefit of this is that invoking the delegate doesn't incur the same performance overhead that using `MethodInfo.Invoke` incurs.

Comment: That's a good solution to my problem as posted, but I'm also doing the same thing with System.Type arrays to pass to Type.GetMethod to specify the parameter types.

Comment: Since `GetMethod` actually takes an array as one of its parameters, I think you're stuck with synchronizing access to the array(s), probably through some kind of lock. Locks can be expensive, so you might find that you're better off allocating short-lived arrays instead.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid that would be the case. No point locking to save time on garbage.